# System.Windows.Forms.Label.Text contents displayed incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, 32bit-64bit

I have a winform with a label. The label has property `Text` set to `abc(123):`

In the designer, the text of the label is viewed as `:(123)abc`.

What is the cause of this?

**Some background information:**

This application worked correctly for years till it was moved from the an old server (Win2003 / 32-bit) to a new server (Win2008 / 64-bit).

The solution was created on an old development-PC (VS2008 / WinXP / 32-bit) and shows the same problem on the new development-PC's (VS2012 / Win8.1 / 64-bit).

Comment: The truth is out there

Comment: @Pietu1998: If a label has a property like `TextDirection` and that property was set incorrectly, it would failed at the old as well as the new environment. Furthermore, I would expect something like: `:)321(cba`.

Comment: Maybe your old system had the incorrect system text direction, and somebody "fixed" it for your application? Just speculating :D

Comment: @Pietu1998: Can you tell me where I can find that text direction in my Windows Environment? BTW: I do not see any 'fixes' in the application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

The controls and labels were places on a TabControl. The original programmer wanted to display the tabs on the right side of the screen, so set the property `RightToLeft` to `Yes` and `RightToLeftLayout` to `True`.

Somehow, on the old systems, this results only in tabs being drawn on the right side. On the new systems this ALSO leads to displaing all its containing labels / textboxes / etc. from right to left instead of left to right. Somehow they now inherit the settings of the parent control.